# Unable to map valid JSON to Objective C Classes

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Consider the following JSON (valid, according to jsonlint) that is being returned from a .NET webservice:

```
{"d":"{\"categories\":{\"category\":[{\"categoryID\":\"edNXeLBcDEa6sAFrxmjoXw\",\"categoryName\":\"Academics\",\"webSiteID\":\"jXKvJ3R85kiAodlhw06FjQ\",\"websiteName\":\"MySite\",\"departmentID\":\"FU0tEh2MCEu54qiVgBX6Yg\",\"departmentName\":\"WebServices\",\"departmentWebSite\":null,\"departmentLogo\":null},{\"categoryID\":\"9QcMMZjMo0G7kMM3kP7Apw\",\"categoryName\":\"Admissions\",\"webSiteID\":\"jXKvJ3R85kiAodlhw06FjQ\",\"websiteName\":\"MySite\",\"departmentID\":\"FU0tEh2MCEu54qiVgBX6Yg\",\"departmentName\":\"WebServices\",\"departmentWebSite\":null,\"departmentLogo\":null},{\"categoryID\":\"Tm207w31ZE6c39DJ1Juk2Q\",\"categoryName\":\"Webinars\",\"webSiteID\":\"jXKvJ3R85kiAodlhw06FjQ\",\"websiteName\":\"MySite\",\"departmentID\":\"FU0tEh2MCEu54qiVgBX6Yg\",\"departmentName\":\"WebServices\",\"departmentWebSite\":null,\"departmentLogo\":null}],\"metaData\":{\"recordCount\":\"3\",\"pageIndex\":\"0\",\"pageSize\":\"0\"}}}"}
```

Doing the following with the serialized JSON works fine:

```
NSDictionary *d = [jsonResults objectForKey:@"d"];
```

This makes the value of "d":

```
{"categories":{"category":[{"categoryID":"edNXeLBcDEa6sAFrxmjoXw","categoryName":"Academics","webSiteID":"jXKvJ3R85kiAodlhw06FjQ","websiteName":"MySite","departmentID":"FU0tEh2MCEu54qiVgBX6Yg","departmentName":"WebServices","departmentWebSite":null,"departmentLogo":null},{"categoryID":"9QcMMZjMo0G7kMM3kP7Apw","categoryName":"Admissions","webSiteID":"jXKvJ3R85kiAodlhw06FjQ","websiteName":"MySite","departmentID":"FU0tEh2MCEu54qiVgBX6Yg","departmentName":"WebServices","departmentWebSite":null,"departmentLogo":null},{"categoryID":"Tm207w31ZE6c39DJ1Juk2Q","categoryName":"Webinars","webSiteID":"jXKvJ3R85kiAodlhw06FjQ","websiteName":"MySite","departmentID":"FU0tEh2MCEu54qiVgBX6Yg","departmentName":"WebServices","departmentWebSite":null,"departmentLogo":null}],"metaData":{"recordCount":"3","pageIndex":"0","pageSize":"0"}}}
```

If I try and call objectForKey of "categories" I just get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error:

```
NSDictionary *categories = [d objectForKey:@"categories"];
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but I can never get more than one layer deep in this JSON. I'm able to make this work in Java, but I'm trying to write an iOS version of my app. Being that I'm new to Objective C I just must be missing something. Any ideas?

**Edit**

Here's what I'm doing in Java with this very same JSON, if that helps:

```
JSONArray arrCategories = null;
String strJson = JSON.postJSONData("http://mysite.com/webservice.asmx/GetCategories", "{'destinationId' : '" + DestinationID + "', 'orderBy' : 'categoryName', 'orderByDirection' : 'asc'}");
String d = new JSONObject(strJson).getString("d");
String strCategories = new JSONObject(d).getString("categories");
arrCategories = new JSONObject(strCategories).getJSONArray("category");
for(int i=0; i < arrCategories.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject objCategory = new JSONObject(arrCategories.getString(i));
    String categoryID = objCategory.getString("categoryID");
    String categoryName = objCategory.getString("categoryName");
}
```

Comment: Instead of a JSON string to be parsed, you have a JSON string that has a JSON string inside of it.

Comment: Yeah, it is what it is. I can't do anything to change what's coming in, unfortunately.

Comment: @Corbin +1 - Ok, I finally caught the importance of what you said! If you post an answer that says basically the same thing I'll accept it. The key was that I needed to use NSJSONSerialization again after I had gotten the string for "d" and then I can get to whatever I need.

Comment: Have done that now.  I thought my comment was clear when I wrote it, but rereading it now, I see that I Should have explained a bit clearer.... Glad you got it though :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have AJAX string.  Well, you do, but the thing is, you have a string inside of it.

The d key maps to a string in the same way that:

{name: "blah"} would map obj.name to the string "blah".

So basically, you need to parse the JSON then parse the JSON inside of the JSON.